# How to use Survey Monkey with integrated Sales Cloud and Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, survey

Thank you for your interesting.

Our client have been done implemented properly with Marketing Cloud and Sales Cloud Core. also, they want to know how to send survey link provided by Survey Monkey within SMS Message through Custom Activity in Journey Builder.

But, They had a one thing that problem when to use Custom activity.
The problem is Our client cannot use standard function. because they want to send a message through domestic numbers. ( In Korea, when sending a message using a mobile studio, it will be send by International number.) For this reason, Only the event entry source must be used.

in my opinion, After create a query activity that stores closed cases in a specific Data Extension, and then, automate Query Activity on an hourly basis in automation studio. I think that it should be stored data such as Contact ID, Contact Name, Case Id, ETC. it's very simply. and using Journey Builder, send message with personalized string to customer who case has been closed. it will be included what that the survey monkey link with personalized string from query activity automation.

I wonder if the above example is suitable for this circumstance.
If not, Please Let me know how to use Survey Monkey in an integrated environment.

Thank you for your answer my question, and I hope you have a great day!

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Salesforce Data Events](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_salesforce_data_event.htm&type=5). Essentially you can utilise this entry event to listen to closed cases and inject the records directly in to a journey assuming you have the related Lead or Contact ID present in this object which seems to be the case according to the [Case](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_Case.htm) field reference object.

**Contact ID on Case object:**

[image]

For the survey part, you need the Survey Monkey link that you should know and can obtain after you create the survey. Store this directly within the content of the activity as the survey link should not change and append the [Personalization String](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_personalization_strings.htm&type=5) of the Subscriber Key as a URL parameter, you can then setup [Custom Variables](https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/What-are-custom-variables-and-how-do-I-use-them) within the survey to retrieve the `id` parameter as per the URL example below.

**Survey Monkey URL Example:**

https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/your_survey?id=%%_subscriberkey%%

Comment: Thank you for the answer my question @thechrishaddad.
Sorry. It's my misake not to talk first.
firstly, our client cannot use the send message as mobile studio. this is because many customers in Korea want to be sent to domestic numbers.
So, one of our partners has implemented custom activity.
for some reason, the custom activity they made, should be execute only specific event entry. I'm not sure if it's a lack of technical skills, but anyway we can't send messages using other event activity. In the case above, is there any other way?

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the 1st answer:
To be EXTRA safe and not pass SF Ids in the clear, it might be a good idea to encrypt the _subscriberkey using encryptsymmetric() AMPscript function before adding it to the survey link, and redirecting survey finishers to a Cloudpage. That CloudPage could then use decryptsymmetric() on the _subscriberkey and create a case in SF.

EDIT: Customizing the end page seems to be a paid feature:

> You can edit the Survey End Page on some paid plans.

https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/What-are-the-Survey-Completion-options

---

regarding encryption, start here:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/de/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-security/manage-your-encryption-keys

Why?

a) It's kind of simple to tamper with SFIds, if you've seen one before.
They are not technically numeric as is discussed here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_microsite_landing_page_security_best_practices.htm&type=5

but they do follow observable patterns. 
So just as a good practice, I'd recommend that.

b) especially since surveymonkey data will fly around in exported excel sheets etc. - you have no idea where your keys will end up.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your advice and addtional information.